# Accessing members in a pointer to a pointer of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Code is as follows:

```
/* set.h */
struct setElement{
  char *element;
  setElement *next;
};

typedef struct setElement *Set;  //Set is now the equivalent of setElement*

Set a;    

setInit(&a);

/* setInit function declaration @ setInit.c */

int setInit(Set *a){
  (*a)->element = "asdf";  //results in a seg fault
}
```

Trying to malloc 'a' works, but if I try to access any member within the set 'a' doesn't work.  I understand I'm passing a reference of the set from the main() function to setInit, so I believe the pointer contained within setInit is addressing the memory allocated by 'Set a' in the main() function, so a malloc wouldn't be required...

Iunno. Help is appreciated :)

Comment: Gah, totally confusing when `Set` is typedef'd to a pointer. Don't do that! Or at least, call it `SetPtr` or something.

Comment: I agree. It is also confusing that `a` is both a `Set` (i.e. a pointer to `setElement`) one place, and a `Set*` (i.e. a `setElement**`) another place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have not allocated the `setElement` you are trying to assign to. In the main part of the code you are creating a `Set`, which is just a pointer to a `setElement`. This pointer is never set to point to anything sensible. I.e. you need something like

```
Set a = malloc(sizeof(setElement));
```

Comment: Even with my sloppy code, you gots it.  I was trying to do malloc() within the initSet.c file as opposed to where they're declared in main().  Thanks man.

Comment: ITYM `sizeof(struct setElement)` (or just `sizeof(*a)`, as I wrote in my answer). Yours won't work in C, only in C++.

Comment: @MattMackie You can do it as well in `initSet()`, but there you should do `*a = malloc(...)`. While having 2 different `a` variables, where the one is the address of the other, it can be confusing for the reader...

Answer (score 1):

Alas, it is unclear where exactly your variables are defined. I assume your `main.c` is something like

```
#include "set.h"

Set a;    

int main()
{
    setInit(&a);
}
```

If so, your a, which is a pointer by itself, should point to somewhere.

If your framework wants `malloc()`ed data, you should do

```
int main()
{
    a = malloc(sizeof(*a)); // *a is a struct setElement now, with 2 pointer-sized members.
    setInit(&a); // Now seInit should be able to operate on the struct as wanted.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @amaurea has mentioned, you'll need to make use of malloc() for your setElement structure. In addition to this, you need to do the same for the setElement struct's `element` member. A `char*` is merely a pointer to a char or char array and will not implicitly allocate anything.

```
int setInit(Set *a){
  (*a)->element = "asdf";  //results in a seg fault
}
```

Could be re-written

```
int setInit(Set *a){
  (*a)->element = malloc(sizeof("asdf"));
  strcpy((*a)->element,"asdf");
}
```

Which the above could be rewritten to take a second parameter of the actual `element` contents.